# Toshiba Satellite M55-S325 XP Recovery CD

Tags: windows-xp

Anybody got a Recovery CD for a Toshiba Satellite M55-S325 laptop... I managed to 'misplace' mine.  I want to refresh the system and reinstall the os (XP) as I haven't done it for a couple of years and my 'lets try this piece of dev software' is now taking its toll...

I've tried google, and also the toshiba site but no luck.

Thanks R.

Answer (score 2):

The most expeditious manner in which to get this restore disk is to call toshiba support by phone.  They actually have these disks in their archive and they will usually sell it to you for about $10.

If you are the impatient type you can always look on bit torrent for the disk.  However I caution you to do so at your own risk.  You might be downloading a "tweaked" restore disk set with some modifications you might not care for.

The straightforward answer is trust the manufacturer before you trust something like this off of bit torrent.